# Version number to WAR file

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, weblogic, jdeveloper, application-server

Is it possible to add version number to WAR file specific to weblogic server ?
To provide build files to client, they want us to get version number in WAR file. Is it possible or is there any standard approach for this ?

PN : Also I'm using jDeveloper as an IDE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is appropriate to add version information to a JAR/WAR manifest file.  See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/packageman.html) for more information.

```
Specification-Title: Java Utility Classes
Specification-Version: 1.2
Specification-Vendor: Example Tech, Inc.
Implementation-Title: java.util
Implementation-Version: build57
Implementation-Vendor: Example Tech, Inc.
```

Answer (score 0):

Other WebLogic components add a revision to the jar (war) file name, e.g.:  xxx_warfile_rev1.0.war. So a "_rev1.0" (or appropriate version) naming is at least consistent with other WebLogic functions. Assuming you're only trying to version the entire .war as a single release, that's probably sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to version the WAR file for weblogic through Manifest.mf file.
If facing the same issue you can have a look at below mentioned URL -

http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/fmw/wls/12c/14-Redeployment--4465/redeploy.htm